# very strange string unique issue in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.0. Here is my code and related exception from ADO.Net. Here is my input two strings in both binary form and text form, any ideas what is wrong? Why the two different strings will be treated as the same by ADO.Net?

Exception message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Column 'Name' is constrained to be unique.  Value '������' is already present.
```

Input strings in binary form and text form:

[image]

[image]

StackOverflow does not display correctly for my code for strings �����, here is screen snapshot for what it actually looks like in my VSTS 2008 editor.

[image]

My code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] buf = new string[] { "����", "������" };

        CompareInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
        ci.Compare(buf[0], buf[1], CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth);
        Console.WriteLine (String.Compare(buf[0], buf[1], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        DataTable bulkInserTable = new DataTable("BulkRequestTable");
        bulkInserTable.CaseSensitive = true;
        DataColumn column = null;
        DataRow row = null;

        // add Keyword column to datatable
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Name";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = true;
        bulkInserTable.Columns.Add(column);

        foreach (string item in buf)
        {
            row = bulkInserTable.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = item;
            bulkInserTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the value of buf[0]==buf[1]? I can't really tell what's going on there with "�" in the strings.

Comment: Thanks JoshJordan, from String.Compare, the output is 0, so it means they are the same. From from display perspective (human eye perspective), they are different. Here is a screen snapshot of VSTS 2008, any ideas what is wrong?

http://i28.tinypic.com/2j10ehg.jpg

Comment: Please refer to my above images, StackOverflow does not display correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, George - if String.Compare returns 0, these strings are considered the same, and trying to insert them both into a column which enforces a unique constraint should not (and does not) work - by design!

Comment: Hi Marc, from display perspective they are different. It is why I am so confused. Any comments?

Comment: I have nothing to add except to say that that is very weird.

Answer (score 4):

I saw you used InvariantCulture in your comparison. You should use Ordinal (character-by-character literal comparison) or CurrentCulture (which takes substitutions into place - like Æ === AE) to do your comparisons.

You might get better luck by entering the characters as Unicode character strings like:

```
string text = "\uEFBF\uBDEF\uBFBD\uEFBF";
string text2= "\uEFBF\uBD0D\uAEFB\uFBDE\uFBFB";
```

I've got this as some Chinese/Japanese characters (not pasting completely):

```
string text = "뷯뾽";
string text2 = "봍껻ﯞﯻ";
```

CurrentCulture will know that a single symbol can represent 2 other symbols, so it would be a good choice to use. Ordinal will just notice that the lengths are different. If they are the same length and each Unicode value is identical for each character, then it will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like Byte-Order marks (BOM) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

The BOMs are probably being stripped on comparison, hence they'll be the same?

Answer (score 1):

When 1 of the strings is converted to be stored in the datatable it is resulting in the same string as another.
so the unique constraint on the dataTable makes it throw an exception.

Comment: Why DB thinks they are of the same? From disply, they are different obviously. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what font or character set those cool characters are in but they don't seem to sort very well. Compare() works based on the sortability of the strings which is why culture is very important for comparing culture sensitive strings. These character strings don't return as different from a sorting perspective so they are in-effect "the same".
The String.Equals() method will show them as different.

```
buf[0].Equals(buf[1]) = false
```

Not sure why the need to use the special characters but if that is a requirement to have as "unique" keys that may be an issue. I am assuming that the datatable is using a similar comparison to validate unique column values and is therefore seeing the two rows as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps turn off the dataTable unique enforcement constraint, and implement your own unique check method?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably related to your character being a special unicode character.

```
"The replacement character � (often a black diamond with a white question mark)
is a symbol found in the Unicode standard at codepoint U+FFFD in the Specials 
table. It is used to indicate problems when a system such as a text parser was
not able to decode a stream of data to a correct symbol"
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Specials